# premake5 how to set outdir based on platform + configuration?

Tags: premake

I'd like to set the outdir/targetdir for each combination of platform + configuration.

```
function SetLibTargetDir(platforms, configs)
for i2,c in ipairs(configs) do
        for i,p in ipairs(platforms) do
            filter ("configurations:" .. c, "platforms:" .. p)
                targetdir("bin/" .. p .. "/" .. c)
                libdirs ("bin/" .. p .. "/" .. c)
                libdirs ("bin_prebuilt/" .. p .. "/" .. c)--manually generated libs/dlls that premake5 can't handle

    end
end
end

SetLibTargetDir({"Win32", "Win64"}, {"Debug", "Release", "Final"})
```

I tried using this code, while it gets the config right(debug/release/final). It places everything in Win64, so the 32 bit files & 64 files all end up in the same directory.

What am I doing wrong here? I'd like each combination of platform + configuration to have its own output dir and library paths.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled across the answer:

https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Tokens

"%{cfg.buildcfg}" get the config
"%{cfg.platform}" gets the platform

So this code works:

```
targetdir("bin/" .. "%{cfg.platform}" .. "/" .. "%{cfg.buildcfg}")
libdirs("bin/" .. "%{cfg.platform}" .. "/" .. "%{cfg.buildcfg}")
libdirs("bin_prebuilt/" .. "%{cfg.platform}" .. "/" .. "%{cfg.buildcfg}")
```